# Clarity on how can `.*` match all strings?

Tags: regex

I guess this is silly question, but I am confused as to how can regex `.*` match all the strings?
`*`: zero or more occurrences of the preceding element,
`.`: matches any one character,

So, in `.*`, `.` should match any one character( say 'x'), then `*` would mean 0 or more occurrences of 'x',
thus giving us strings like:
"",
"x",
"xx",
"xxx",
"xxxxxxx",.. etc.

But how is it able to match any random string like "ab12b3v34"?
Shouldn't this be actually the case for `[.*]*`?

What am i missing here please explain.

Comment: @Thefourthbird - No it does not - `[.*]*` uses the set containing either `*` or `.` It uses this set to match zero or more times. In addition anchors `$` and `^` should be used

Comment: The period is not required to be the _same_ match every time.  In the regex `...`, would you expect that to match only `xxx`, `yyy`, etc?

Comment: @JohnGordon, `.*` here period is matching only once right? And after that the matched character is considered for `*`. Am I correct?

Comment: No, "the matched character" is not considered for the `*`.  "any character" is considered.  So the match is "any character, any character, any character, ..."

Comment: @JohnGordon, for pattern `.` its `any character(one time)` then, why for `.*` it becomes `any character(0 or more time), any character(0 or more time),...` instead of `any character(0 or more time)`?

Comment: I've explained it as well as I can.  `.*` means "zero or more occurrences of any character".  If you have deeper questions, please consult the regex documentation.

Comment: @EdHeal Of course you are right, I don't know what I was thinking there. It is a character class `[.*]` matching either an asterix or a dot.

Comment: @Insouciant `.` does not match any character. It matches most characters except new line on most regular expressions. Need to flip it into multi-line mode

Comment: @EdHeal, noted. thanks. my doubt is cleared.

Comment: I think this question lacks clarity and/or is opinion-based. "*How can `.*` match all strings?*": There is no answer other than that it is defined as such (by most, if not all, regex engines).

Comment: The expression to match the same character any number of times is `(.)\1*`. Explicitly matching and capturing one character, then requiring that to be followed by the character matched by capturing group 1.

Comment: @deceze, thanks i see the difference now.

Answer (score -1):

My confusion was due to my ignorance of order of evaluation.
I thought the evaluation went as follows(which is wrong):

1. In `.*`, `.` is evaluated first, say `.` is replaced by 'x'. Here 'x' is just a literal character.
2. Then `x*` would be evaluated leading to strings like "", "x", "xx", "xxx", ...etc.
3. Thus my doubt as to how it produced strings like "ab12b3v34".

But the correct order of evaluation is:

1. In `.*`, `*` is evaluated first, thus resulting in another regex pattern like  , `.`, `..`, `...`, ...etc, where `.` are still wildcards.
2. Then the wildcard `.` is/are replaced by any character, thus resulting in  string(without new-line character) such as "ab12b3v34"(in this case from `.........`).

Thanks to all who commented for your patience.